# Obtener lista en function para insert

Tags: c#, foreach

Estoy leyendo un `excel` en esta `function` `excelInfo`, ya estoy recorriendo las filas y columnas no hay problema,

```
   public string dataTable()
    {    

        DataTable excelTable = new DataTable("ExcelFile");
        DataTable original = GetDataTableExcel();


        int renglon = 1;
        fileExcelInformation fileExcel = new fileExcelInformation();
        List<fileExcelInformation> lista = new List<fileExcelInformation>();

        foreach (DataRow item in original.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < original.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                //
               switch (original.Rows[0][i].ToString())
                {

                    case "XXXXX":

                        fileExcel.XXXXX = item[i].ToString();
                        break;

                    case "XXXXXX":

                        fileExcel.XXXXX = item[i].ToString();
                        break;

                    case "XXXXX":

                        fileExcel.XXXXX = item[i].ToString();
                        break;

                    case "XXXXX":

                        fileExcel.XXXXX = item[i].ToString();
                        break; 

                    case "XXXXX":

                        fileExcel.XXXXX = item[i].ToString();

                        renglon += 1;
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
               lista.Add(fileExcel);
            }                              
        }
        lista.Add(fileExcel);

        Save();
        return "" ;
    }
```

pero al terminar de leer el documento voy a la `function` de `Save`, donde debo de hacer un `insert` de los valores recolectados anteriormente
el problema es que no se como implementar un foreach para recorrer la lista o algo parecido, por lo que así
simplemente obtengo valores `null` en cada una de las propiedades en los `comand`,y de hecho el `insert` funciona, solo falta obtener los datos.

```
public void Save()
    {
        fileExcelInformation fileExcel = new fileExcelInformation();
        string conexionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["principal"].ConnectionString;

        using (var conexion = new OracleConnection(conexionString))
        {
            try
            {
                string sql = "INSERT XXXXX(XXXXXX,XXXXXXX,XXXXXXX,XXXXXXX,XXXXXX) VALUES (:XXXXXXX, :XXXXXXX,:XXXXXXX,:XXXXX,to_Date(:XXXXXXXX,'yyyy/mm/dd'))";
                conexion.Open();

                using(var comand = new OracleCommand(sql,conexion))
                {


                //foreach()  aqui va el foreach para recorrer y obtener los datos
                //{
                        comand.Parameters.Clear();
                        comand.Parameters.Add(":XXXXXXX", fileExcel.XXXXXXXX);
                        comand.Parameters.Add(":XXXXXXX", fileExcel.XXXXXXXX);
                        comand.Parameters.Add(":XXXXXXX", fileExcel.XXXXXXXX);
                        comand.Parameters.Add(":XXXXXXX", fileExcel.XXXXXXXX);
                        comand.Parameters.Add(":XXXXXXX", fileExcel.XXXXXXXX);
                        comand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                //}
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pero en si cual es tu pregunta ? que no sabes como implementar un `foreachs` ? necesitas saber como implementarlo ?

Comment: Asi es que cosa de lo que tengo va dentro del foreach para obtener los datos y poder hacer el insert.

Comment: haz el `for` sobre la variable  `lista` ya que es sobre la que estas escribiendo los valores  cuando haces  `lista.Add(fileExcel);` , ahora lo que no entiendo es `fileExcelInformation` no conozco esa Clases, ¿ tienes documentación de como funciona la clases `fileExcelInformation` ? para que hagas `get` de los valores.

Comment: Necesitas hacer in insert por cada item de `fileExcel` ???

Comment: El foreach seria `foreach (fileExcelInformation itemFileExcel in lista) { .... }`

Answer (score 3):

Puedes utilizar un **`foreach`** de esta forma Suponiendo que esto  `":XXXXXXX",` es la definicion de cada campo de la tabla en la que haces el insert  :

```
public void Save()
    {
        fileExcelInformation fileExcel = new fileExcelInformation();
        string conexionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["principal"].ConnectionString;

        using (var conexion = new OracleConnection(conexionString))
        {
            try
            {
                string sql = "INSERT XXXXX(XXXXXX,XXXXXXX,XXXXXXX,XXXXXXX,XXXXXX) VALUES (:XXXXXXX, :XXXXXXX,:XXXXXXX,:XXXXX,to_Date(:XXXXXXXX,'yyyy/mm/dd'))";
                conexion.Open();

                using(var comand = new OracleCommand(sql,conexion))
                {


                foreach(var item in fileExcel)  aqui va el foreach para recorrer y obtener los datos
                {
                        comand.Parameters.Clear();
                        comand.Parameters.Add(":XXXXXXX", item.propiedad1);
                        comand.Parameters.Add(":XXXXXXX", item.propiedad2);
                        comand.Parameters.Add(":XXXXXXX", item.propiedad3);
                        comand.Parameters.Add(":XXXXXXX", item.propiedad4);
                        comand.Parameters.Add(":XXXXXXX", item.propiedad5);  
                        comand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

En el `foreach` se van a ir agregando los parámetros y cuando termine realiza el `insert` por cada item que llega en `fileExcel`